# Port Config in amazon ec2 for WebSocket

Tags: amazon-ec2, websocket

I am trying to write something on WebSocket with Amazon ws. The problem is that I can not open the port by running this :

> conn = new WebSocket('ws://ec2-54-213-181-25.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8081');

My port config on inbound and outbound in security for TCP and ICMP are all range 0-65535 and destination 0.0.0.0/0. But I still cannot open port 8081. 
Can anyone tell me the wrong thing I did?

Comment: Do you have any service listening on port 8081? You can use `netstat -l` to find out out.

Comment: From the results, it's not. What should I do to open or use the port? see readyState = 3, I know that I cannot open the ws

Comment: You have opened up the security group, which is your access from the outside. Now you need to have a service running which is listening to that port. What stack are you running?

Comment: I am new to Amazon ws , but under CloudFormation Stacks, there is no stack running. I installed nodejs to test what was running on my local machine. Please help.

Comment: You need to run something on your instance that will listen and respond to your web socket requests. An EC2 instance is just a virtual machine running whatever software, services you want to have it run.

Comment: i am running >node app.js on the server, where app.js calling app.listen(8081); How can I run it permanently on ec2? Or everytime i need to run nodejs

Comment: You should be able to run it as a deamon. Are you using something like this: http://blog.nodejitsu.com/keep-a-nodejs-server-up-with-forever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pointed out that I need to open the port by this way :

> socket = io.connect("abc:123");

so they are the same websocket version

Answer (score 2):

You have to create your websocket in private ip of Your EC2. Then you can connect your websocket using your public ip or url with port number

Comment: This worked out for me, I'm using React to create a php websocket server. I had to check for the instance private ip with `ifconfig` and attach the server to it. I had already opened the port I used on amazon configuration and on vps configuration.

Comment: Deserves more upvotes, pretty much hit every google result there was, thank you